# Count and performs an insert or an update

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

Hi i want to know if is it possibile to do this thing in only one query.

```
$qryString="SELECT * FROM votes WHERE userID='$userID' AND messageID='$messageID'"; 

$qry = $pdo->prepare($qryString);
$qry->execute();

$resultArray=$qry->fetchAll();
$num=count($resultArray);

if ($num==0)
{$qryString= "INSERT INTO Votes (userID, value, messageID) VALUES ('$id', '$value', '$messageID')" }

else
{ $qryString = "UPDATE votes SET value='$value', WHERE userID='$id' AND messageID='$messageID' " }
```

Doing that i will perform at least two queries. It's a "grotesque" method (with performance ripercussions) or this is the right way?

Comment: not only does it have performance repercussions, but is has a race condition, where another process inserts the same record(or deletes it) in the time span between those 2 sql queries, causing the second query to fail. a transaction can remedy that, but `on duplicate key update` is better here.

Comment: uhm, in the worst case it simply retrieve an error, or it will obstruct the entire DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumine `userID` has a unique index:

```
INSERT INTO Votes (userID, value) VALUES (:id, :value)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

Also, since you're using PDO, you should be using placeholders in the prepared statement, not interpolating variables, as I showed above.

Comment: userID is not unique because one user can perform much votes. I've siplified the code above, indeed the check is on userID and messageID. I now update the question

Comment: For the placeholder question, it's only for avoid the SQL injection, right?

Comment: @AnnaLica **NO**. It is to make your query run without errors.

Comment: @AnnaLica userID **and**  message is an unique identifier, isn't it?

Comment: userID + messageID = unique because naturally an user can vote a message once

Comment: When I wrote my answer there was no `messageID` in the question. The queries in the question implied that `value` was only dependent on `userID`. In any case, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` should do the right thing as long as there is some unique key in the table and the `INSERT` covers it.

Comment: yes i said that initially i've posted a semplified version of the real script. Anyway i didn't understad what i should do now.
There are no unique keys in the table, except the ID of votation, but it useless for my case

Comment: You wrote above `userID + messageID = unique`. So add a unique index to enforce that.

Comment: You mean that i should insert a field that contains userID-messageID (for exemple 23-321). I could use that such primary key instead of use an auto_increment method

Comment: No. Just create a unique composite index on the userID and messageID fields. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uid_mid ON Votes (userID, messageID)`

Comment: there is a way to create this type of field through phpmyadmin?

Comment: I don't use phpmyadmin. Doesn't it allow you to enter plain SQL queries?

Comment: So, i've created the unique index 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/801/9op.png/

now i would want to uderstand: it's unnecessary to assign a primary ID key into the table, right? The sql query is the same posted above in your first message?

Comment: That's correct. Just use the SQL in my answer. Any attempt to create a duplicate of a unique index triggers `ON DUPLICATE KEY` processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

**Getting the Count**
Use the MYSQL count function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE UserID='$id';
```

This will return a single scalar (the number of records) which saves PHP from fetching the entire result set

Secondly, You are completely correct in making the decision to update or insert in the code. Logic belongs in the code, not in the database. It could be done using Barmar's answer, and is a question of style.

**References**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: So you wouldn't use `Insert...on duplicate key...`?

Comment: Doing it in a single statement avoids race conditions (which can also be solved using transactions).

Comment: I assumed that because Votes is a Votes table, not a user table, UserID would not be unique, hence there could be many values. If it is unique, then duplicate key works fine (as the code seems to suggest by updating if more than one)

Comment: Barmar, your solution elegantly solves the problem from an SQL perspective, and would offer performance improvements over mine (as such should be the selected answer in this case). You are correct about the race conditions.

Of course, this is predicated on UserID being a unique key constraint (which it should be if it is impossible for a user to vote more than once)